# orderByChild() not working for me in Firebase Realtime Database in flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

My data structure is something like this in my firebase database in my flutter app

```
...
"search" : {
   "titles" : {
       "title0" : {
           "Likes" : 3
        }
        "title1" : {
           "Likes" : 5
        }
        "title2" : {
           "Likes" : 9
        }
   }
}
...
```

I want my "titles" to be ordered by the number of "Likes", but this doesn't work and gives me this error:

```
final firebase = FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .ref('search/titles')
        .orderByChild('Likes');
final snapshot = await firebase.get();
```

[image]

which is strange because my firebase rules are open

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
  }
}
```

If instead of the `orderByChild()` I put `orderByKey()` it perfectly works, so I'm clueless because the rules are open and nothing should block the `orderByChild(...)`.

Also if I put `orderByValue()` it doesn't work.

Why does ONLY `orderByKey()` work and not `orderByChild(...)` or `orderByValue()`?

if instead of the "orderByChild()" I put "orderByKey()" it perfectly works, but it isn't what I want because it orders my titles by name

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem, so posted an answer below (just because the info is too long for a comment) with what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce the problem.

When I set up a minimal repro in Zapp.run with this code:

```
final db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('77820695/titles');
final snapshot = await db.orderByChild('likes').get();
for (var child in snapshot.children) {
  print(child.key);
}
```

It prints:

> [07:30:03] title0
> [07:30:03] title1
> [07:30:03] title2

The `77820695` in the code is what I named the node in my database, and this is how I set the rules for that node:

```
"77820695": { 
  ".read": true, 
  "titles": { 
    ".indexOn": "likes" 
  } 
},
```

You can find the working example here: https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-zv2g06rlv2h0

If the problem persists for you, can you create a similar Zapp.run instance where you get the error?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I'm trying right now but it's a little bit complicated. One question: do i need to add the rule ".indexOn" on that particular path? If it is so it might be the problem. My rules are just open but i didn't add that ".indexOn" anywere.

Comment: Yes, you do need to have an index on the data you want to order on. But not having an index will lead to a different error message than the one you get.

Comment: Well i don't know why it gave me the wrong error but putting the ".indexOn" solved my problem. Thank you so much for putting this effort in making me find the answer! I hope I can find you again someway if I have any other problem! Thank you, you saved my day